# Why does a connection have to be open for a nonquery but not to fill a dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, windows, database-connection

When I connect to a SQL datasource in my C# application, I can fill a dataset using the following code. Note that I am not explictly opening a connection to the datasource.

```
SqlConnection cw_con = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=Database;User=User;password=password");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Example WHERE value = value");
cmd.Connection = cw_con;

//Create DataSet
DataSet cw_ds = new DataSet("cw_ds");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
//Execute Command and Fill DataSet
da.Fill(cw_ds);
cw_ds.Clear();
```

However, If I want to execute a nonquery such as a `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE` why do I have to explicitly open the connection by using `connection.Open();`?

```
SqlConnection cw_con = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=Database;User=User;password=password");
cw_con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE example SET value = value WHERE value = value");
cmd.Connection = cw_con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cw_con.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because a `DataAdapter` opens the connection implicitely when it's closed initially. It'll close it afterwards if it was closed before, otherwise the connection stays open.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx):

> The Fill method retrieves the data from the data source using a SELECT
>   statement. The IDbConnection object associated with the select command
>   must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the IDbConnection
>   is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data and
>   then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it
>   remains open.

When using a `SqlCommand` you must explicitely open and close connections yourself.

**As a side note**:

1. Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid SQL-Injection
2. Use [using-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for anything implementing `IDisposable`, especially Connections since it ensures that it gets disposed/closed as soon as possible, even in the case of an error

Answer (score 3):

From the [DataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx) documentation

> If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to
>   retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is
>   called, it remains open.

When you use the SqlCommand you're using a lower level class, so you're expected to manage the connection yourself.

Here's a use case where you wouldn't want the connection to automatically be opened because it would be opened and closed several times and its better to simply throw the exception

```
SqlCommand InsertCmd = new ("Insert statement", cw_con)

cw_con.Open();

foreach (var newitem in collection)
{
   --Set Parameters
   UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

cw_con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that

> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT
>   statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before
>   Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx) for more information.